# Old age isn’t pleasant. / Old age isn’t a joy

Tags: phrase-choice

Do you have an idiom or a common expression about the following: "Old age isn’t pleasant. / Old age isn’t a joy."? It's a translation from my native language. I try to say that in their younger days one's life was better, more curious, jollier, with good health.

Comment: I'd put it, "Aging is no fun/There's no joy in old age/It's no fun to be old".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common one I've heard is "Getting old stinks/sucks." (AmE)

Comment: As I understand it, that phrase is very informal. It looks like rude expression, isn't it? What about another phrase? I need a little bit warmer words, maybe, with some nostalgia.

Comment: It is informal, and the latter can be offensive. You are right. Ok, fair enough.

Comment: "The feet are slow when the head wears snow." - sounds good, but it's used rarely. Do you use it in the US?

Answer (score 2):

Given how the old person doesn't like the current situation and wants to reminisce **the good old days** it is quite fitting to come across as somewhat rude. So FeliniusRex's answer of ***Getting old stinks*** could be quite fitting.

If you want to focus more about what was better about the past you word it exactly like that, as something in the past:

> - When I was your age I could easily lift ...
> - In the good old days we actually talked to each other over dinner.
> - We used to play in the woods for hours, climbing trees, chasing rabbits, those were the days ...

When thinking about someone in the situation where it's relevant to say *old age isn't a joy* I fail to picture anything other than a grumpy old grandpa who complains to everyone around him, hence why I cannot think of an idiom that means the same but doesn't have that *grumpiness* to it.